# Duplicate "Dynamic Web Project" within Spring Tool Suite

Tags: java, eclipse, duplicates, copy-paste, fork

How do I copy my project that is based on "Dynamic Web Project" template within Spring Tool Suite? When I try the usual copy & paste in the Project Explorer I get this error from the Pivotal tc Server:

> Two or more Web modules defined in the configuration have the same
>   context root (/DynamicWebProject). To start this server you will need
>   to remove the duplicate(s).

I want to fork my current project - basically duplicate it with another name. I am on Spring Tool Suite 3.6.2.

Answer (score 0):

For the second project change the value for

```
Project Properties>Web Project Settings>Context root
```